# Upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 as it is released now but the updater only shows version 21.04. Even if I try to upgrade to 21.04 first: as soon as it comes to the point to upgrade something with the package resources it does only say that there is some error which most likely was caused by packages not supported by Ubuntu or something like that and it tells me to use ppa-purge command from the ppa-purge package to delete launchpad apps. I don't understand this. Please help! How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10?

Comment: Take a look here please. https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: You do not the upgrade method. There is no supported, tested path to skip releases using the upgrade method, with the sole exception of LTS-to-next-LTS. The supported method is to use a LiveUSB and install the new version over the old -- there's an option in the installer for this.

Comment: Can I install Ubuntu 21.10 and keep all of the other cusomization like software and themes?

Comment: You've not said if you're talking about a desktop or server install; but you can *upgrade via re-install* easily (I QA-test & use this feature very often, for Lubuntu it's an actual *testcase*).  You just use existing partitions & do not format. Only system directories are wiped (so any global settings may get lost inc. server app configs; but user configs used by desktop systems won't be touched as they're in $HOME), new system installed, & *manually installed* packages are auto-added (if available in Ubuntu repositories for new release) added back. It's very flexible for desktop installs

Comment: for a laptop development box already on a LTS release ( 20.04 ) I would sit tight until the next LTS is released ( 22.04 ) which happens every 2 years ...  if you manage to upgrade onto a NON LTS release namely any release in an odd year or the xx.10 release that box will get stuck there unless you actively upgrade during the 6 month window just after its follow on release happens ... in other words if you forget to upgrade a NON LTS box you cannot upgrade once that box falls behind this 6 month release cycle ... so best to always only use the current LTS release then stick to LTS on next rel

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed only upgrade from one Ubuntu version to the next, or from one LTS release (Long Term Support release) to the next. 20.04 is a LTS. You can upgrade to 21.04, but you also will be able to upgrade to the next LTS, 22.04.

The system may not be customized too much in order to upgrade.

- [Disable any PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) you added
- Fully update your system before attempting the upgrade:

  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  sudo apt dist-upgrade

Then you can update with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If you do not get the update going, then the shortest pain will be a fresh install - overwriting your existing installation. Technically, that is by far the best, even though you then need to restore all your customizations.

Comment: So I actually decided to install Kubuntu 21.10 because I wanted to use KDE Plasma and I didn't really have much storage left. Will I be able to upgrade to Ubuntu or Kubuntu 22.04 LTS? What would be the timeframe for that? How would I do it? Is there anything you can say to this?

Comment: Yes, but this is a Q&A site, and I gave my answer to your current question.

Comment: Yes but is it so difficult to just try to answer my new question? It's not always necessary to create an own question for everything I want to know? It's related to this one.